# checking health on every second

Tags: android

Hello i have really no idea of how to do this i have tried with timer and CountDownTimer but i cant figure out how to complete it. What i want to do ? I wanna do on every second the Health to go down by "-1" after passing the "20" to show Dialog which will say

```
Title: "Low Health"
Message: "The dog health is going low give him some food" 
Button: "Got it"
```

I have this code and when ill start the application its closing/crashing automatic i dont know what to do please help:

```
Timer myTimer = new Timer();
        myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Health -= 1;
                if (Health <= 20) {
                    if (!canSeeWarnDialog) {
                        lowFood();
                    }
                    canSeeWarnDialog = true;
                }
            }
        }, 0, 1000);
```

Thank you.

**EDIT:**
I want this action to go on 1 minute i tell 1 sec. cause of faster testing ...

Comment: What error messages do you get in LogCat ?

Comment: Please post the error messages you get and show us whant the methods in the code snippet above do.

Comment: Show the lowFood() method too.

Comment: `08-08 17:17:51.632: E/AndroidRuntime(949): at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:107)
08-08 17:17:51.632: E/AndroidRuntime(949): at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:114)
08-08 17:17:51.632: E/AndroidRuntime(949): at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:931)
08-08 17:17:51.632: E/AndroidRuntime(949): at com.lazydog.rafa.MainActivity.lowFood(MainActivity.java:172)
08-08 17:17:51.632: E/AndroidRuntime(949): at com.lazydog.rafa.MainActivity$3.run(MainActivity.java:114)
08-08 17:17:51.632: E/AndroidRuntime(949): at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)`

Comment: `void lowFood() {
  final AlertDialog alertDialog2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(
    MainActivity.this).create();
  alertDialog2.setTitle("Im hungry");
  alertDialog2.setMessage("The dog health is going low "
    + "\ngive him some food");
  alertDialog2.setButton("Got it", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
   }
  });
  alertDialog2.show();
 }`

Comment: @Stefan You're missing the actual error message. And can you edit your question with the code snippets?

Comment: i have posted the errors in the my 2nd comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, the health will have a certain value and you want to decrease it by 1 every second. If that value reaches below 20, then you want to call lowFood() right? Here's something you can try (I've tested this on a real device and updated the answer ):

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.post(new Runnable() {

    boolean run = true;
    int health = 200;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(run) {
            health = health - 1;
            if(health < 1) {
                lowFood();
                run = false;
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Its just showing white background and after some time saying application need to close and two buttons "Wait" and "close"

Comment: @Stefan i've update the answer, please check with this new code.

Comment: actually working, but just one more thing after showing the first time the dialog doesn't showing second time for example i will give food on the dog and after passing that 20 health need to show again but can't .. :D EDIT: and the white background is still here till doesn't show the alert dialog

Comment: Hum not sure I understand you, but if once we set run to false, then it stops checking very second. You will have to recreate that handler if you want to continue to start checking events again.

Comment: so i will need to change it to "true" ? and what to do for that white background ?

Comment: I have change it like this `if(Health <= 20) {
                  lowFood();
                  run = false;
              }
`

Comment: i need to change the `run = false` to `run = true` ?

Comment: can u show me how to make the timer to return counting after showing the dialog ?

Comment: You can't make it continue counting if you set run = false; Check that the while loop is only active if run = true. So, as soon as you set run = false, that while loop becomes inactive.

Comment: So that means i need to change `run = true` ?

Comment: do you have any solution henrique ? :/

Comment: Maybe you can try moving that "run" boolean outside of the Handler and control it from outside? That way you can have more control of exactly when to start/stop that handler.

Comment: Now don't even start because of that white background ... If you want you can add me on Skype: stefanrafaa ill show you the whole project if you want to see thanks :)

Comment: OK guys any solution of the problem ? :S